# PowerShell to Import Excel Data into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

Totally new to PS, however, I'm attempting to use it to write a PowerShell code that imports an Excel file into SQL Server Studio.

I'm using the following link to as a reference but am getting the following error in my code:

**ERROR:**

```
Get-ExcelSheetInfo : The term 'Get-ExcelSheetInfo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

**CODE:**

```
$File = "Q:\Data Requests\ED TO BED TEST\ED_TO_BED_DAILY.csv"
$Instance = "SERVER_NAME_X"
$Database = "DATABASE_NAME_Y"
$fileName =  [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($File)
foreach($sheet in Get-ExcelSheetInfo $File)
{
$data = Import-Excel -Path $File -WorksheetName $sheet.name | ConvertTo-DbaDataTable
$tablename = $fileName + '-' + $sheet.Name
Write-DbaDataTable -SqlInstance $Instance -Database $Database -InputObject $data -AutoCreateTable -Table $tablename
}
```

https://tsql.tech/load-data-directly-in-sql-server-from-a-xlsx-file-without-oledb-or-excel-using-powershell/

Comment: Pardon me if I am stating the obvious, but did you install the ImportExcel and DBATools modules?

Comment: The is correct, I did not - thank you!